# Conditionally render p:selectOneRadio based on checked values of p:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two checkboxes.

```
<h:panelGrid id="userActivationGridcheckbox">
    <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{user.activationModecheckbox}" layout="pageDirection">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Account Expiration(in days)" itemValue="byEmailcheckbox" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reset User Password" itemValue="byAdmincheckbox" />  
        <f:ajax event="change" render="userActivationGridcheckbox" /> 
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>

    <h:panelGrid id="manualActivationGridcheckbox" rendered="#{user.manualActivationcheckbox}" columns="2">
        <p:selectOneRadio value="#{user.activationModecheckbox}" layout="pageDirection">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="label1" itemValue="value1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="label2" itemValue="value2" />
            <h:outputLabel>label</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText value="" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

When the first checkbox is checked, then 2 more radio buttons should show up. When the second checkbox is not checked, then the radio buttons should not show up. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Will need to see your bean code to help you

Comment: It's not valid to have a label and input field as child of `<p:selectOneRadio>`. What exactly were you trying there? In future questions, please eliminate code noise yourself so that you end up with the smallest possible code which still demonstrates the problem for you (and thus also us) in a completely blank playground project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide in some listener method whether or not to show the radio group to the user, for example, by keeping a boolean in a backing bean. Then just render the component via AJAX.

Example usage:

The view:

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="check" value="#{bean.options}">
        <p:ajax process="@this" update="radio" listener="#{bean.listener}" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="Option 2" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
    <h:panelGroup id="radio" layout="block">
        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{bean.needsSuboptions}" columns="2">
            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.suboption1}" layout="pageDirection" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select ---" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suboption 1-1" itemValue="Suboption 1-1" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suboption 1-2" itemValue="Suboption 1-2" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.suboption2}" layout="pageDirection" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select ---" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suboption 2-1" itemValue="Suboption 2-1" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suboption 2-2" itemValue="Suboption 2-2" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

And the bean:

```
List<String> options;//getter+setter
String suboption1;//getter+setter
String suboption2;//getter+setter
boolean needsSuboptions = false;//getter

public void listener() {
    needsSuboptions = options.contains("Option 1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do with f:ajax as the code that skuntsel provided.

```
<f:ajax render="" execute="" listener=""/>
```

maps to:

```
<p:ajax update="" process="" listener=""/>


<p:selectManyCheckbox id="check" value="#{displayPanel.options}">
            <f:ajax event="change" render="radio" listener="#{displayPanel.listener}" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="Option 2" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
        <h:panelGroup id="radio" layout="block">
            <h:panelGrid rendered="#{displayPanel.n}" columns="2">
                <p:selectOneRadio value="#{displayPanel.a}" layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select ---" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suboption 1-1" itemValue="Suboption 1-1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suboption 1-2" itemValue="Suboption 1-2" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>
                <p:selectOneRadio value="#{displayPanel.b}" layout="pageDirection">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select ---" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suboption 2-1" itemValue="Suboption 2-1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suboption 2-2" itemValue="Suboption 2-2" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

you forgot the provide listener for f:ajax.